# Does Xamarin support class library project reference nesting, generating an AndroidManifest.xml for components in nested references?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-manifest

Does Xamarin support multiple levels of project reference nesting, where the referenced project includes Android components intended for the AndroidManifest.xml?

For example: AndoidXamarin App > ClassLibrary1 > (which declares a Service) ClassLibrary2 (which also declares a Service):

```
// ClassLibrary1:
// Referenced by the XamarinApp 
// References ClassLibrary2

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [Service(Exported = true, Name = "com.company.test." + nameof(ClassLib1Service))]
    public class ClassLib1Service : Service
    {
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```
// ClassLibrary2 
// Referenced only by ClassLibrary1

namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    [Service(Exported = true, Name = "com.company.test." + nameof(ClassLib2Service))]
    public class ClassLib2Service : Service
    {
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```
// The generated `AndroidManifest.xml` only includes the Service defined in ClassLibrary1.

  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:name="android.app.Application">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:name="crc64a7a6b04b89628087.MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.company.test.ClassLib1Service" />
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="1999999999" android:authorities="com.company.test.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
  </application>
```

Comment: Take a look at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.ManifestMerger/1.0.0-preview03 and see if that solves your issues. Xamarin uses their own manifest merging tool in the current stable version, but have announced they are switching to the one in the NuGet package in the near future.